# Application breaks after dispatching ngRx action

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a reducer like this:

```js
export type Action = SensorsActions.SensorsActions

const defaultState: ISensor[] = []

export function sensorsReducer(state: ISensor[] = defaultState, action: any){
  switch (action.type){
    case SensorsActions.ADD_SENSOR:
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case SensorsActions.DELETE_SENSOR:
      return state.filter(s => s.id !== action.payload.id)
    case SensorsActions.UPDATE_SENSOR:
      let number = state.findIndex(s => s.id == action.payload.id)
      const sensors = [...state]
      sensors[number] = action.payload
      return sensors
    case SensorsActions.SET_SENSORS:
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And there is an Observable state:

```js
  sensors$: Observable<ISensor[]>
  constructor(
    private sensorsService: SensorsService,
    private store: Store<SensorsTableState>
  ) {
    this.sensors$ = this.store.select('sensors')
  }
```

And there is a table in UI with sensors(objects). I have a button which filters this objects:

```js
  <button class="search-button" (click)="filterSensors()">

  filterSensors(): void {
    if (this.searchQuery !== undefined){
      this.sensors$.subscribe(sensors => {
        const result = filterSensors(sensors, this.searchQuery)
        this.store.dispatch(new SensorsActions.SetSensors(result))
      })
      this.setPages()
    }
  }

export const filterSensors = (sensors: ISensor[], query: string): ISensor[] => {
  return sensors.filter(sensor => {
    return Object.values(sensor).find(value => {
      const isValidValue = value && (typeof value === "string" || typeof value === "number")
      return isValidValue && value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
    })
  })
}
```

And problem is that when i click the button, my application breaks and i can't even refresh my page, but there are no errors in console and terminal. Method which filters works correctly and returns needed objects, i checked in console. Reducer should work correctly, because in method `ngOnInit()`, where i get sensors from server and set them using same dispatch works correctly too, so, what a problem?

Comment: Looks like you will get in a loop as you dispatch the action which sets the sensors, which will fire the selector and thus execute your subscribe body which dispatches the action again. Without looking too deeply you should be dispatching a filter action with query from your button click and then handle the filtering itself in the reducer.

Answer (score 1):

The Observable of sensors$ emits a value for every change in the state, and you listen to this Observable and change the state inside the subscribe method, so it triggers an infinity loop.
you can add `pipe(take(1))` to the sensors Observable to fix this issue